# How to run a class within a different class?

Tags: java, class, symbols

**[LINK TO GITHUB TO SEE THE CODE](https://github.com/Blackflames64/Casino)**

I am new to programming.

I am trying to run a class called roulette.java within a class called casino.java

Casino.java has a switch case statement and when the case is called the following code runs:

```
roulette.main(args);
```

both files have:

```
package casino;
```

at the very top and are within a folder called casino.

I get the error

`cannot find symbol
   symbol:   variable args
   location: class casino.casino`

Please note: Everywhere I search for an answer to this tells me to put that exact same code, do I need the "args" part? I want to load the whole class from the start.

Comment: it simply tells you that the variable `args` isn´t within a scope it can be accessed from. without seeing more of the code that´s the only thing one can say here.

Comment: Show the code of both classes; the one from which you're calling, and how you're calling and the method which you're calling?

Comment: I have added a link to github to see the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `args` is not defined.
You can for example define it like this

```
String[] args = new String[]{};
```

And call that method then

```
roulette.main(args);
```

Or you could just call it like this:

```
roulette.main(new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I think it tells you when you invoke the main method from  roulette.java, the codes roulette.main(args) is not proper. The main method's format is public static void main(String args[]), String args[] means the method needs String array as argument to run.